# 5th BUSINESS DAY subscription SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report subscription that needs to send out on the 5th business day of the month, right now i can run it on the 5th of the month but the user wants it to be on the 5th business day so that it does not get sent out on weekends. How do I create a schedule that runs it on the 5th Business day of the month.

2008r2 using BIDS.

Thanks.

Comment: "business day" is a nebulous term. easiest would be to schedule a recurring job to run on the 1st, which calculates the 5th business day for that particular month, and schedules a 1-shot job to run your report on that day.

Comment: ok, can you point me to some reference on how to go about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internal working of SSRS subscription is executing a Agent Job. The schedule of subscription is also based on the SQL Agent Job schedule. However, this build-in schedule doesn't support "business day". For your requirement, the most approximate workaround is selecting ever first some weekday of every month.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Black_T, I've gotten more help from you today than I've gotten in the few months that i have been on here.