# How to make SSRS subscriptions Kick off on Business Day 6 of month

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Found a similar question
[5th BUSINESS DAY subscription SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173380/5th-business-day-subscription-ssrs)
But in that case a work around -schedule for 1st  of month- was suggested and accepted as the answer.

I want to know if anyone has found a clever way to make SSRS subscriptions run on a specified Business Day. I.E run on Business Day 6. This is not just to prevent the report from going out on a weekend, but also because certain Finance operations related to closing the month have an agreed upon date (EX. "Will be done by BD 3") And I need my report to run after that each month.

One comment also suggested setting up a sql agent job to calculate what BD X would be each month, and insert a SQL job for that date to kick off the Report. I can see in theory how this would work - but the subscription wouldn't be managed within SSRS then and could easily be over-looked in the future.

I have been getting by with the following imperfect code:

```
--: returns last day of last month (DT), but only provides a result row if we are on BusinessDay X of the month.
--No rows returned prevents the report from being processed & sent. 
--SSRS Schedule must be set to run monthly in a range covering all possible Calendar Days that could be Business Day X 
declare @dt datetime = Getdate(), @BDTarget int = 6
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1,@dt)-1, -1) as DT,sum(dimdate.BusinessDay) as BD
FROM DimDate 
where FullDate between  DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @dt), 0) and @dt
having sum(dimdate.BusinessDay)=@BDTarget
```

Though recently discovered that this logic can kick off the report two days in a row, for example if we are looking for BD 6, this month July 2021 the above query returned a row on both Friday 7/9 and Sat 7/10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a data-driven subscription that runs daily.
Use a query that will only give a result on the 6th business day.

e.g.

```
WITH cte_6th
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dimDate dd
    WHERE dd.TheMonth = MONTH(current_timestamp)
    AND dd.TheYear = YEAR(current_timestamp)
    AND dd.BusinessDay = 1
    ORDER BY dd.Date
    OFFSET 5 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_6th c
WHERE c.Date = CAST(current_timestamp as DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

For an instance of SQL Server Standard, where data-driven subscriptions are not available, I worked out a way to use the *Comment* field of the subscription to provide the work day within the month, so that updates to multiple reports are not needed.  It requires a working day in month function (also included below) and a SQL CLR Regex routine, or you could replace the regex pattern with a T-SQL "LIKE".  The following routine should be run in a scheduled job to "pick up" any changes to subscription comments.  It will wrap the "add_event" command with a check for business day in month.  When the SQL Agent / SSRS schedule fires, then the event will only be added for the specified work day in month.

```
CREATE OR ALTER procedure ModifyJobStepsForSsrsWorkDayInMonth
AS
BEGIN /* For SSRS environment without data-driven subscriptions, modifies SQL Agent jobs 
            to only run on specified work day in month.  An email will be sent each time this procedure
            is run, if there were any jobs steps to update.

            Prerequisites: SSRS, dbo.RegexMatch (SQL CLR routine), function WorkingDaysMonthToDate()

            To enable, include the following phrase in the subscription comments:
            WorkDayInMonth=nn
            where "nn" is one or two digits.  The phrase may be anywhere in the comment but must be delimited 
            from other text.  For example:
            WorkDayInMonth=2 requested by accounting (usable)
            Accounting requested WorkDayInMonth = 2  (usable)
            HesaidWorkDayInMonth should be = 2 (NOT usable, no spaces and words inserted before "=")

 3/24/2023  INITIAL Release

EXECUTE MyDatabase.dbo.ModifyJobStepsForSsrsWorkDayInMonth

To test: 
1) Get today's working day (must be positive):
   SELECT MyDatabase.dbo.WorkingDaysMonthToDate(DEFAULT)
2) Update a subscription to: a) run on this day of the month, and b) to include the appropriate comment
3) EXECUTE MyDatabase.dbo.ModifyJobStepsForSsrsWorkDayInMonth
4) Manually execute the SQL Agent job that was modified and expect to receive the results from SSRS
*/

DECLARE cReportSchedules CURSOR LOCAL FOR
        SELECT sj.[name] AS [Job Name],
                 sj.job_id AS "JobId",
                    sjs.step_id AS "StepId",
               rs.SubscriptionID, 
                    TRY_CONVERT(XML, su.ExtensionSettings).value('(/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name="Comment"]/Value)[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)') 
                       AS SubscriptionComment,
               c.[Name] AS [Report Name],
               c.[Path],
               SJS.command

/* Relationship between SSRS Subscription and SQL Agent job

   SSRS.ReportSchedule.ScheduleID  --> sysjobs.[job]name
                                       sysjobs.job_id --> sysjobsteps.job_id
                   .SubscriptionID --> ReportServer.Subscriptions
                                             Subscriptions.Report_OID --> Catalog.ItemID
                          SubscriptionID <-- sysjobsteps.command (as procedure parameter)  */

FROM msdb..sysjobs AS sj 
     JOIN ReportServer..ReportSchedule      AS rs  ON sj.[name] = CAST(rs.ScheduleID AS NVARCHAR(128)) 
      JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps              AS SJS ON SJS.job_id = sj.job_id
     INNER JOIN ReportServer..Subscriptions AS su  ON su.SubscriptionID = rs.SubscriptionID
     INNER JOIN ReportServer..[Catalog]     AS c   ON su.Report_OID = c.ItemID

DECLARE @ExistingCommand     nvarchar( max),
        @JobId               uniqueidentifier,
        @JobName             SYSNAME,
        @NewCommand          nvarchar( max),
        @ReportName          nvarchar ( 850),
        @ReportPath          nvarchar ( 850),
        @SqlCommand          nvarchar ( max),
        @StepId              int,
        @SubscriptionComment nvarchar(4000),
        @SubscriptionID      uniqueidentifier,
        @WorkDayInMonth      tinyint,
        --                                    Match WorkDayInMonth = dd (1 or two digits ONLY)
        --                                    The key phrase needs to be at the beginning and/or end of the Comments field, or
        --                                    needs to be delimited by white-space and non-digits (at the right end)
        @WorkDayPattern      nvarchar(4000) = N'(?i)(?:^|.*\s+)WorkDayInMonth\s*=\s*(?:(?<Days>\d{1,2})(?:$|[^\d]+))'

OPEN cReportSchedules

FETCH NEXT FROM cReportSchedules
                INTO @JobName,                      @JobId,                @StepId, 
                          @SubscriptionId,               @SubscriptionComment,
                            @ReportName,                   @ReportPath,
                            @ExistingCommand

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    --Following query for debugging only:
    --SELECT @JobName         AS "@JobName",        @JobId               AS "@JobId",               @StepID     AS "StepId", 
    --         @SubscriptionId  AS "@SubscriptionID", @SubscriptionComment AS "@SubscriptionComment",
    --         @ReportPath      AS "@ReportPath",     @ReportName AS "@ReportName",
    --         @ExistingCommand AS "@Command"

    SET @WorkDayInMonth = TRY_PARSE(SharedRoutines.dbo.RegexGroup(@SubscriptionComment, @WorkDayPattern, N'Days') AS tinyint)

    -- Create or update the wrapped "exec" statement

    IF @ExistingCommand LIKE '%AddEvent%TimedSubscription%' + ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(36), @SubscriptionId), '{null}') + '%' AND
        @WorkDayInMonth BETWEEN 1 AND 31    
        BEGIN
        SET @NewCommand = 'IF (SELECT MyDatabase.dbo.WorkingDaysMonthToDate(DEFAULT)) = ' +
                                                    ISNULL(convert(varchar, @WorkDayInMonth), '{null}')             + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                                '   BEGIN'                                                                     + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                                '   exec [ReportServer].dbo.AddEvent @EventType=''TimedSubscription'', ' +
                                                                                '@EventData=''' + ISNULL(convert(varchar(36), @SubscriptionId), '{null}') + '''' 
                                                                                                                                         + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                                '   END'

        -- following lines FOR DEBUGGING ONLY
        --PRINT @ExistingCommand
        --PRINT @NewCommand 
    
        IF @NewCommand <> @ExistingCommand
         BEGIN
            SET @SqlCommand = 'UPDATE TOP(1) msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps'                                           + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                                    '       SET Command = @NewCommandParm '                                        + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                                    '       WHERE job_id = @JobIdParm AND '                                        + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                                    '             step_id = @StepIdParm'

           EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt = @SqlCommand,
                                         @params         = N'@JobIdParm uniqueidentifier, @StepIdParm int, @NewCommandParm nvarchar(max)',
                                        @JobIdParm      = @JobId,
                                           @StepIdParm     = @StepId,
                                           @NewCommandParm = @NewCommand
         IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
                BEGIN
             -- create notification or log entry here
                DECLARE @iNotify bit = 0
                END -- Updated something

            END -- New command is different

        END -- Command matches basic expectations

    FETCH NEXT FROM cReportSchedules
                         INTO @JobName,                      @JobId,                @StepId, 
                                @SubscriptionId,               @SubscriptionComment,
                                @ReportName,                   @ReportPath,
                                @ExistingCommand
    END -- loop

END -- procedure 
GO
```

The following function requires a basic "Holidays" table:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.WorkingDaysMonthToDate(@TestDate date = NULL)

                         RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
/*
    Calculate the number of working days from the beginning of the month
     through @TestDate.  

     If @TestDate is not itself a work day, return the value as a negative number.

    Core algorithm from: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calculating-work-days

NOTE: The following expression is used below to eliminate dependence on
      either region (DATENAME) or side-effects of @@DATEFIRST:
      -- In this expession, 0 is always Sunday and 6 is always Saturday
        (((DATEPART(DW, <<DateToTest>>) - 1 ) + @@DATEFIRST ) % 7)


 3/16/23  INITIAL RELEASE

SELECT dbo.WorkingDaysMonthToDate(NULL) -- today
SELECT dbo.WorkingDaysMonthToDate(GETDATE())
SELECT dbo.WorkingDaysMonthToDate('7/5/2023') -- 2 - the 3rd and 5th

*/

IF @TestDate IS NULL
    SET @TestDate = GETDATE()

DECLARE @FirstOfMonth date
DECLARE @Multiplier   smallint

SET @FirstOfMonth = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@TestDate), MONTH(@TestDate), 1)

-- Check to see if @TestDate is itself a working day

IF (((DATEPART(DW, @TestDate) - 1 ) + @@DATEFIRST ) % 7) IN (0, 6) OR
   EXISTS(SELECT * 
                  FROM dbo.Holidays
                      WHERE HolidayDate = @TestDate AND
                            IsWorkDayAtMyOrganization = 0
            )
    SET @Multiplier = -1 -- ABS(<<<ReturnValue>>>) gives the number of working days so far,
                         -- @TestDate is NOT a working day
ELSE
    SEt @Multiplier = 1 -- <<<ReturnValue>>> gives the number of working days through @TestDDate,
                        -- @TestDate is a working day


RETURN (-- Total days including @TestDate
             (DATEDIFF(dd, @FirstOfMonth, @TestDate) + 1) -
             -- Subtract number of whole weeks
             (DATEDIFF(wk, @FirstOfMonth, @TestDate) * 2) -
             -- Subtract for the beginning date is Sunday or the end date is Saturday

             (CASE WHEN (((DATEPART(DW, @FirstOfMonth) - 1 ) + @@DATEFIRST ) % 7) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - 
             (CASE WHEN (((DATEPART(DW, @TestDate)     - 1 ) + @@DATEFIRST ) % 7) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -

             -- subtract all observed holidays in the range
             (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Holidays
                    WHERE HolidayDate BETWEEN @FirstOfMonth AND @TestDate AND 
                            -- in this expession, 0 is always Sunday and 6 is always Saturday
                            (((DATEPART(DW, HolidayDate) - 1 ) + @@DATEFIRST ) % 7) NOT IN (0, 6) AND
                            IsWorkdayAtMyOrganization = 0 -- i.e. a "real" holiday
             )
        ) * @Multiplier
         

END -- WorkingDaysMonthToDate
GO
```

And finally, the Holidays table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Holidays](
    [Holidayid] [int] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    [HolidayName] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [HolidayDate] [date] NULL,
    [IsWorkDayAtMyOrganization] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](1000) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Holidays] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Holidayid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
) ON [PRIMARY]
```